# C-ares get ns records

Tags: c, dns, c-ares

I'm using [c-ares](http://c-ares.haxx.se/) for my **DNS** queries. The problem is, i don't know how to get **NS** values. I didn't find any examples and docs are not enought for me :(

Man page for [ares_parse_ns_reply](http://c-ares.haxx.se/ares_parse_ns_reply.html) provides only function description. I've already created my channel and figure out how to make **gethostbyname** queries:

```
    // ...
    status = ares_init_options(&channel, &options, optmask);
    if (status != ARES_SUCCESS) {
        printf("ares_init_options: %s\n", ares_strerror(status));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    // ...
    ares_gethostbyname(channel, "stackoverflow.com", AF_INET, callback, NULL);
    // ...
```

But what do i do next to get MX/NS/AAAA records ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After many hours:

```
static void callback_ns(void *arg, int status, int timeouts, unsigned char *abuf, int alen)
{
   struct hostent *host = NULL;
   ares_parse_ns_reply(abuf, alen, &host)
   // your result now in "host" variable
}

ares_query(channel, "stackoverflow.com", ns_c_in, ns_t_ns, callback_ns, NULL);
```

Comment: `ns_c_in` and `ns_t_ns` values are defined in <arpa/nameser.h> (based on [documentation](http://c-ares.haxx.se/ares_query.html))

Comment: Well done on the research. The c-ares docs, a term that one can only use in the loosest possible sense of the word, are woeful with a lack of examples (aside from a couple of old utilities) as well as partly missing with broken links all over the place at http://c-ares.haxx.se/docs.html. Really a shame.